# using a robot to save a web page with different names

Tags: java, url, selenium, autosave

I am using `selenium` to create a robot that opens a page and save it automatically, as follow:

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7043856");

Robot robot = new Robot();

robot.delay(20000);


robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);    
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

There are two problems, first of all, it actually does not press enter and only opens the `save as` window and second, how can I make it to pass a different name or at least, do not override pages when the file name are same?

Comment: why are you using Robot? Can't you just use driver.getPageSource() to get the source and save it as a file?

Comment: @Cyril I tried all these ways and it does not work (at least) for `IEEE xplore` which contains academic pdfs. I tried also other methods to load the pdf link andsave the page, agaon, for ieee it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. When we use driver.getPageSource() the css, scripts and related resources do not get saved and cannot be viewed offline properly.

I was able to save the file using the same code. It was only a matter of adding a `Thread.sleep()` after each operation.

Notice that when the Save As window opens up the, focus is on the file name. So you can use the Robot class to input a file name. Regarding your problem with the file name should not get overwritten you can use a random number generator. You might have to create a function for making this task easy.

Please check the code below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7043856");

    // Added this line to let the page load completely
    String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();

    Robot robot = new Robot();

    // Press Ctrl+S
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    // Generate a 2 digit random number and split it into two separate chars
    String random = RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(2);
    System.out.println(random);
    char charOne = random.charAt(0);
    char charTwo = random.charAt(1);

    // Save As window has opened and the focus is on the file name field.
    // Click right arrow key to go to the last of the already present name
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);

    // Append the generated random number to the name
    robot.keyPress(getKeyEvent(charOne));
    robot.keyRelease(getKeyEvent(charOne));
    robot.keyPress(getKeyEvent(charTwo));
    robot.keyRelease(getKeyEvent(charTwo));

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    // Press enter
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

}

public static int getKeyEvent(char key) {

    switch (key) {
    case '1':
        return KeyEvent.VK_1;
    case '2':
        return KeyEvent.VK_2;
    case '3':
        return KeyEvent.VK_3;
    case '4':
        return KeyEvent.VK_4;
    case '5':
        return KeyEvent.VK_5;
    case '6':
        return KeyEvent.VK_6;
    case '7':
        return KeyEvent.VK_7;
    case '8':
        return KeyEvent.VK_8;
    case '9':
        return KeyEvent.VK_9;
    default:
        return KeyEvent.VK_0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer rocks!! But can the sleep for thread become shorter?

Comment: I think the Thread.sleep() after the `Ctrl + S` operation should remain as 5 seconds because the Save As window takes some time to open(It could also be more than 5 seconds depending on your system load). You can reduce the other one.

Comment: There is another question. Are you sure the function produces random integers for, say, 1000 instances?

Comment: Currently produces only random numbers in 100 range ... You can modify the code for increasing the range -  RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(4). Also modify the robot code accordingly.

Comment: Ok. sorry to have another question. I was wondering how to order the robot to close the window? it might be useful to use `mousepress` and click it at the top right corner side of screen but the browser does not opens full screen. how to let the browser to open full screen? or is there any easier way to close window?

Comment: Use selenium - driver.quit()

Comment: but this might close the window half way through of page saving.

Comment: In Firefox ctrl + j would open the downloads window of Firefox. You can use robot to open this. Check if driver.quit() closes this window also. If not, download will complete successfully